# Unique EventListener ID in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I'm currently creating `eventListeners` using the following:

```
client.on('data', function(data){
    // Lots of other functions etc..
});
```

What I would like to know specifically, is whether it is possible to identify this particular listener by a unique ID so that I can refer to it individually?

There may be multiple instances of this `eventListener` open at any time and I want to be able to remove them based on receiving a specific data event that will refer back to this ID. The issue right now is, I have no idea how to identify individual `eventListeners`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can always store your listener function to a variable and add or remove it like this:

```
var EventEmitter  = require('events').EventEmitter
    emitter       = new EventEmitter();

var addListener = function(id){
  var listener = function(){
    console.log("Listener", id);
    emitter.removeListener("test", listener);
  }
  emitter.on("test", listener);
}

addListener("a");
addListener("b");

emitter.emit("test");
// Listener a
// Listener b
```

With this you have a unique id by having the listener variable that refers to the listener function. In that scope you can remove the listeners based on the scope.

Comment: What's the overhead of creating and destroying the event listener each time the event is fired? Some events can be pretty common (25ms is plausible in one application of mine).